# How to display table data ordered by another table data row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have **videos** and **watch_later** MYSQL tables, and I want to display **videos** data in a page ordered by **watch_later** date, my current **videos** table looks like this

```
id  |  name         | views
1   |  funny video  | 40
2   |  sad video    | 20
```

And my current **watch_later** table looks like this

```
id  |  video_id  | date
1   |  2         | 2016-02-01
2   |  1         | 2016-02-02
```

I've tried selecting all ids from **watch_later** table ordered by date and then selecting all data from **videos** table where id IN (previous ids), but that doesn't get me the **videos** data ordered by **watch_later** date.

(If I didn't make sense, I just want to do a watch later system like YouTube.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to perform a query with `JOIN` syntax:

```
"SELECT videos.*, watch_later.date 
 FROM videos 
 JOIN watch_later ON videos.id=watch_later.video_id
 ORDER BY watch_later.date DESC"
```

If you prefer sorting in ascendant order, replace `DESC` with `ASC`.

With this query, you will select either the `videos` fields and the `date` from `watch_later` table.

There are various `JOIN` methods: if you want study it, look at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

#### Edit:

I choose to select all fields of `videos` and **only** `watch_later.date` because of `watch_later.id` field: using the `SELECT *` syntax, in fact, make that fields are overwritten by following fields with same name, causing - in this specific case - the loss of `videos.id` in the result.

Comment: What is the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` ?

Comment: @zakaria They are functionally equivalent. There are two other types of `JOIN`: `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`; when we use different join types in the same query, it's good practice to specify `INNER JOIN` for clarity, but not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

just need to join the tables, on the video_id field:

```
SELECT * FROM videos INNER JOIN watch_later 
  ON videos.id=watch_later.video_id 
  ORDER BY watch_later.date dESC
```

Comment: That gave me wrong data for some reason, I've tried your syntax `"SELECT * FROM videos INNER JOIN watch_later ON videos.id=watch_later.video_id ORDER BY watch_later.date DESC"`, but it gave me wrong data for some reason, for example if I added a video with id 1 to watch_later, in watch_later page it select to me a video with id 23, 23 isn't the video_id, it's the watch_later id !!

Comment: @zakaria - if you use `select *` you'll get the id column from both tables. if you dont want it, replace it with `select videos.id, videos.name, videos.views, watch_later.date  FROM ...`